# Deleting docs in a collection using Angular in Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a document and its nested documents in a collection inside the document in Firestore in Firebase using Angular. As of right now, I can delete said document and collection, but not without the compiler throwing an error at me `error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'`. The error code might be right or wrong, I do honestly not know, as my code does find the id associated with the object I'm looking at. This is my code:

```
testID: string;
private testDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Test>;

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

deleteDoc() {
    console.log('Deleting test');
    this.db.collection(`tests/${this.testID}/questions`, ref => ref.orderBy('order'))
        .valueChanges().subscribe(questions => {
            questions.map(question => {
                this.db.doc(`tests/${this.testID}/questions/${question.id}`).delete()
                    .catch(error => {console.log(error); })
                    .then(() => console.log(`tests/${this.testID}/questions/${question.id}`));
            });
        });
        this.testDoc.delete().catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

I have tried to pass 2 arguments in the map function as well but that just throws errors in the executed function instead of the compiler, thus making the code not work at all (I might not be passing the right thing here).

As I've mentioned, my code works, but I am most definitely doing something wrong. So my question is, what am I doing wrong to trigger a compile error and how do I avoid this while making sure the function still works? Hope someone can help clarify what it is I am doing wrong here.

Thank you in advance.

*Edit, included the doc I'm looking at

```
export interface Question {
    description: string;
    order: number;
    type: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    options?: Object[];
    radio_amount?: number;
    current_chips?: Object[];
    imageURL?: string;
}
```

Comment: does your `question.id` has the id field or you expecting the key?

Comment: It has the field id I believe yes. I've updated the question to include what I'm looking at.

Comment: what is this part of code doing `this.testDoc.delete()`?

Comment: The test is the main document while the questions are sub documents in the collection nested under the main document.

It is deleting the document with the nested collection that is the questions. However, deleting a document does not delete the nested collections.

Comment: it looks like you just declared it, and nothing assigned to it. then how delete work?

Comment: Sorry your question confuses me sir. The function in which you question does exactly what it is supposed to do, it deletes the document referenced as testDoc, that works just fine. The other part of the code collects the ids of the docs in the collection nested under the test document. Then it deletes each document by referencing the question.id from the document which is the name of the document.

Comment: This error is pretty explicit: it says you don't have an `id` property in your question. You are either not saving your question `id` to Firebase or, if you want Firebase's provided key, you're not mapping it as the [example docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges).

Comment: I already am saving the key as the ID in Firebase and it is there and the above mentioned code works. The error only shows up while compiling, but the code is still compiled and the function does delete the nested documents correctly. The ID exists, otherwise it would not be able to delete any of the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that I was missing the type on the variable I was looking at, I did however not know how to declare the type of that variable in a arrow function as trying to include external variables into the function did not work for me.

I fixed my error by adding the type as seen in my code here. Now the code works just like before AND it does not give me a compiler error.

```
deleteDoc() {
    this.db.collection(`tests/${this.testID}/questions`,
        ref => ref.orderBy('order')).valueChanges().subscribe(questions => {
        questions.map((question: Question) => {
            this.db.doc(`tests/${this.testID}/questions/${question.id}`).delete()
                .catch(error => {console.log(error); })
                .then(() => console.log(`Deleting question (${question.id}) in (${this.testID})`));
        });
    });
    this.testDoc.delete().catch(error => console.log(error)).then(() => console.log(`${this.testID} has been deleted.`));
}
```

I appreciate the help a few of you have tried to give me, but you seemed to be more focused on the fact that my code did not work when that was never the case or the question. The focus was on the error I specified in the question thrown by the compiler despite the function working and how to write the code correctly to not throw the error.

Quick heads up, I do not recommend using the above mentioned function since this is currently running while subscribed to the collection of questions and is thus also running the code several more times as the value changes when I delete the docs during the function. It works, but it is not optimized.